# Real time website for vehicle location and database R/W in java

Tags: java, database, multithreading, server, real-time

I work in a company with a real time vehicle location website for our clients. Clients vehicle's send 1 TCP packet per second with all information about the vehicle (battery voltage, speed, RPM, doors states, DTC, fuel level, fuel consumption and ....). We have clients with 5 to 10 vehicle and some others with 30 to 50 vehicle.

In the server side we have a java application that receive these information form TCP socket and decode them and write it in a database. Inside the code the person that programmed it before me used a database pooling (BasicDataSource). The way it was made is when a packet is received a thread is created for the packet, the packet is decoded and the information is wrote into the database inside the thread, database connection is closed. After processing a packet the thread ends. Sometimes we get so many packet per second that the application create 100 to 200 connection to the database.

I am a C++ programmer and i know how to program in java, but I'm not an expert so i want to know if it's really a good idea to do it like that. The way i want to do is i have a FIFO, with data producer and data consumer, the data producer fill the FIFO and the data consumer empty the FIFO. What i was thinking is to create a connection and keep it open and write my data continually because I have (when we add up all vehicle packets) at least 80 to 100 packet per second, so I don't really need to close it because I will have only two thread, producer and consumer. (so i write inside the consumer each time I empty the FIFO)

I searched in the internet and i found in many place that the way I want t do it is not a good way. But I don't know what will be the best for our situation, I want to eliminate the creation of too many thread and creation of too many connection to the database. What a java and database expert think about the way I can improve this application.

(The website i talked in the beginning of the post is a external server that connect to this database and get the last data written into the database and show them into the HereMap map. So the real time part of the system is really important)

Here a URL to another questions related to the same application (for some performance issues) [How to improve a Java application working with BasicDataSource object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33129860/5420624)

Comment: Is this really a website, or are you listening to a TCP port in a daemon or similar?

Comment: @NevilleK Yes you are right I forgot to talk about this part, it's a website that read the last data written into the database and show it inside a website

Comment: "Too many threads" - really? Hundreds of threads is fine. Thousands is probably fine. Do you actually have a quantifiable, reproducable problem, or do you just not like the design?

Comment: Here the link of my test that i made with the application, you can see that the application has many performance issues http://stackoverflow.com/q/33129860/5420624

Comment: @NevilleK I think hundreds of threads is fin, thousands too, but the application create threads and they only run for some mili second. It means that the application create 100 thread every second. I'm not a Java expert, but in C++ creating a thread cost much time and destoying it too, so it's not a good idea to create thread so often.

Answer (score 1):

Creating and abandoning connection to database is not good approach, if you have constant flow of data.

The frameworks (like Spring) usually creates one connection to database and keep it open "forever". (well, they can abandon/restart it, if something is not happening for a long time etc.)

Actually the nicest and in future extendable way would be to create REST API, which would handle this requests. Use framework (like Spring) and it will handle a lot things for you. You can "decode" packets and send them as API requests.

The good thing about this is that it can be easily used just by any technology or any approach in future without creating completely new solution or rewriting actual code.
Even customer can do it by himself, if you give him access and if he wants. You just give him API documentation and everything else depends on him.

Comment: The problem with existing application in company is the company don't want another solution. What they want is to improve the existing code. A colleague proposed this solution and they doesn't want to create another way to do it. It's an often problem in company, if something works they only want to keep it like that and they don't want another solution, they say, we have something that already works, it's the only thing about what they thinks. But what do you think we can do with the existing application.

Comment: @CaptainWise - Well captain, your solution does not sound bad, can you refer some articles which says it is "not a good way"?